# How to delete a row from the list in zend framework 1.12.18

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

Hi i just started to learn zend framework going through CRUD operations in zend framework 1.12.18.Everything is working fine insertion,update and delete.But facing some while deletion i am using jquery for displaying pop up while clicking on delete button it is deleting but displaying that record in front end when i refresh the page the record disappears.Can any one check this.Here is my Code.

EmployeeController

```
public function deleteAction()
{
$request = $this->getRequest();     
$mapper = new Application_Model_EmployeeMapper();
$mapper->delete($this->getRequest()->employeeid);   
}
```

index.phtml

```
<td><button id="<?php echo $entry->employeeid; ?>" class="delete"> Delete</button></td>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".delete").click(
    function(){
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var rowElement = $(this).parent().parent(); 
        alert("Are you Sure you want to delete");
        $.ajax({type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'employee','action' => 'delete','id'=> $this->escape($entry->employeeid))); ?>',
        data: {'employeeid':del_id},
        success:function(data) {
        if(data!="YES") {   
            rowElement.fadeOut().remove(); 
            alert("success");
        }else { alert("erro");
        }}
        });     
    });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me this please it will be thankfull

Comment: Hi can anyone help me these please it will be helpfull thanks in advance